# Sodaq - How do you toggle the "switched" groove connectors with a Sodaq Moja

Tags: arduino, microcontroller

How do you turn the power on and off in software for the "Switched" side of the grove connectors on a Sodaq Moja?

I know its a matter of "turning off the ground". What is an example of code that does that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to do it. While it is really not documented there is an accidental hint under section "2. Programming the SODAQ board"  at http://www.sodaq.net/#!getting-started/c21ma.

"Pin 6 is normally used for switching power to the Switched row of Grove connectors, but for now we just use it because it has an LED too."

The digital pin 6 powers both the led and the actual grove connectors as well. Here is some sample code.

```
void setup()
{
    pinMode(6, OUTPUT);
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
    digitalWrite(6, HIGH); // Turns on both the LED and the power
    delay(400);
    int value = analogRead(A0); // read your analog sensor that needs power
    digitalWrite(6, LOW); // turns off the power
    Serial.println(value);
    delay(1000);
 }
```